# Module installed but not recognised by PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, python-module

I'm trying to use the Speedtest module on Mac. I've already installed the module using

```
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % pip3 install speedtest-cli
Requirement already satisfied: speedtest-cli in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.1.3)
```

However, when I try to import it on Python, PyCharm suggests me to install the module `speedtest`. I'm confused because the module would have to be imported successfully, but it seems that it's not found and, when I try to install the suggested module, it's not the one that I want to use.

Here is some information that might be useful.

```
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % pip --version
pip 21.2.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % python -m pip --version
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip
macbook@M1-Mac-JC ~ % pip3 --version
pip 21.2.4 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: I think this issue can be avoided altogether if you use virtual environments, which is the best practice. Here is an [article](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) from Real Python which explains how they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are using a different python environment in PyCharm than the one you installed the module for. For example you might be using the python 2 in Pycharm while you installed the module for python3